# Random answer Android studio Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, button, random, view

I'm a beginner and I wanted to make a code that will print "yes" or "no" on random when the button is clicked. (Using kotlin) here's my code
package com.example.calculator

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.view.View

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fun buttonPressed(view: View){
            val randomword = Random. ("yes" or "no")
            textView.text = randomword
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [`Random`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/) class for the things you can generate randomly. You can produce different types from the range of all their possible values, or you can provide a range yourself (e.g. between this `Int` and that `Int`). Then you can use those values for useful things, like generating a random index, that kind of thing.

Since you have two values here, you might just want to use `Random.nextBoolean()` to pick between them:

```
val randomWord = if (Random.nextBoolean()) "yes" else "no"
```

So basically that `nextBoolean()` call evaluates to *true* or *false*, and the `if` condition checks that, and returns one of those two strings. Easy enough, right?

---

But another thing Kotlin has is the [`random`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/random.html) function on its collections. Basically if you have a collection (list, array, map etc) you can call `random()` on it to get a random item. This is better than trying to generate an index and then `get` that item (although there might be cases where you want to do that too)

So you can create a collection of responses, and pick one at random:

```
val responses = listOf("yes", "no")
val randomWord = responses.random()
```

Answer (score 0):

to get a random item ("yes" or "no" in your case), you can do

```kotlin
val options = listOf("yes", "no")
val randomWord = options.random()
textView.text = randomWord
```

and then you may put the above code in an onClickListener for a button in your activity / fragment using [viewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) or [findViewById](https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-android/access-a-view-programmatically-using-findviewbyid/) to reference both the textView and the button

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```kotlin
fun buttonPressed(view: View) {
    val randomInt = (0..1).random()
    if (randomInt == 0) {
        textView.text = "yes"
    } else {
        textView.text = "no"
    }
}
```